# How can I get a range of line every nth interval using awk, sed, or other unix command?

Tags: unix, sed, awk, cat

I know how to get a range of lines by using awk and sed.
I also do know how to print out every nth line using awk and sed.

However, I don't know how to combined the two.

For example, I have a file with 1780000 lines.

For every 17800th line, I would like to print 17800th line plus the two after that.

So if I have a file with 1780000 lines and it starts from 1 and ends at 1780000, this will print:

```
1
2
3
17800
17801
17802
35600
35601
35602
# ... and so on.
```

Does anyone know how to get a range of line every nth interval using awk, sed, or other unix command?

Answer (score 5):

Using GNU sed:

```
sed -n '0~17800{N;N;p}' input
```

Meaning,

```
For every 17800th line: 0~17800
  Read two lines: {N;N;
  And print these out: p}
```

We can also add the first three lines:

```
sed -n -e '1,3p' -e '0~17800{N;N;p}' input
```

Using Awk, this would be simpler:

```
awk 'NR%17800<3 || NR==3 {print}' input
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So if I want to print 100 lines after nth line, I need 100 of N; 's or is there a easier way?

Comment: Yes you need 100 N's, in that case awk is clearly th way to go.

Comment: but you can also use a script to generate the sed script

Comment: One way to `program` the number of `N`'s using GNU sed is `sed -n '0~17800{:a;N;s/\n/&/2;Ta;p}'` where you replace `2` by the number you require.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat file
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

$ awk '!(NR%3)' file
3
6
9

$ awk -v intvl=3 -v delta=2 '!(NR%intvl){print "-----"; c=delta} c&&c--' file
-----
3
4
-----
6
7
-----
9
10

$ awk -v intvl=4 -v delta=2 '!(NR%intvl){print "-----"; c=delta} c&&c--' file
-----
4
5
-----
8
9

$ awk -v intvl=4 -v delta=3 '!(NR%intvl){print "-----"; c=delta} c&&c--' file
-----
4
5
6
-----
8
9
10
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
seq -f %.0f 1780000 | awk 'NR < 4 || NR % 17800 < 3' | head
```

output:

```
1
2
3
17800
17801
17802
35600
35601
35602
53400
```

## Explanation

1. The `NR < 4` is for the first 3 lines because the requirement `For every 17800th line, print 17800th line plus the two after that.` doesn't fit the output you gave.
2. Here I use `head` for reducing the output size and you should remove it in your use case.
3. For GNU seq, you don't need `-f %.0f`.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` solution that skips ***ALL*** division/modulo/per-row-counter ops, and updates the tracker's value only once every N rows :

```
jot 80000 |
```

---

```
mawk 'NR == (_? _ : (__ = ___ + !+_)^(_ = "+" (+_))),
      NR == __  &&   __ = ___ + (_ += ____)' ___=2 ____=17800
```

---

```
1
2
3
17800
17801
17802
35600
35601
35602
53400
53401
53402
71200
71201
71202
```